# CMake and Visual Studio 2010 source_group doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

We have been using Visual Studio 2009 plus cmake and the source_group function to groups the source files. After we moved to Visual Studio 2010, we noticed that the source_group doesn't work any more.

This happens with cmake 2.8.6 or 2.8.10 on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel.

Comment: Is this a question? Did you search in the CMake bug tracker for a report about this? (If it's not a question, and it's just an observation, then perhaps reporting it to the CMake bug tracker would be more effective....)

Comment: I've used source_group successfully in MSVC 2008, 2010 and 2012. There is no MSVC 2009. Perhaps you're using it wrong somehow. Add a minimal example of the problem if you want more help.

Comment: Is USE_FOLDERS ON or OFF (set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON))?